# Create a dictionary from a list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I got a list of multiple tuples like it for example :

```
[(1,2,3),(1,10,11),(5,7,8)]
```

and my aim is to obtain it :

```
{1:{2,3,10,11},5:{7,8}}
```

thanks for  reading me

Thanks, it workds but I must have only unique value, and I don't want to have list

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve. To convert that exact list of tuples into that dictionary, or is there a pattern you are trying to follow?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
l = [(1,2,3),(1,10,11),(5,7,8)]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for k,*t in l:
    d[k].update(t)
```

Or with a python `dict` we can use `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = dict()
for k,*t in l:
    d.setdefault(k, set()).update(t)
```

---

```
print(d)
{1: {10, 11, 2, 3}, 5: {8, 7}}
```

Comment: Tip: to get a normal dict from the defaultDict use `dict(d)`

Comment: OP wanted a set as a value in the dictionary.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for editing @RiccardoBucco , perhaps you could've updated both ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like below:

- Go through each tuple in the list for e.g. (1, 2, 3) ( `for t in l` )
- Then check if the first element in the tuple is in the dictionary i.e. dictionary has already a key with that value? ( `if t[0] in s` )
- If yes, then update the value which is a set with the new elements in the tuple excluding the first element - because first element is the key ( `s[t[0]].update(set(t[1:]))` )
- It not, then create an item in the dictionary with key = first element and value = set( remaining elements ) ( `s[t[0]] = set(t[1:])` )

```
    l = [(1,2,3),(1,10,11),(5,7,8)]
    s = {}
    for t in l:
      if t[0] in s:
        s[t[0]].update(set(t[1:])) 
      else:
        s[t[0]] = set(t[1:])
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
{1: {10, 11, 2, 3}, 5: {8, 7}}
```

If you want your set (value) in each item in the dictionary to be sorted, you could use a [`ordered-set`](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/) or some manipulation on [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: thanks,it works  but to be honest, I don't rly unterstand what you did

Comment: @jean_pierre I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
tuples=[(1,2,3),(1,4,5),(2,4,7)]
keys=set([i[0] for i in tuples])
result={}
for key in keys:
    dummy=[]
    for t in tuples:
        if t[0]==key:
            dummy.append(t[1:])
    result[key]=dummy
```

Edit: reducing loops

```
result={}
for k, *t in tuples:
    if k not in result:
        result[k] = t
    else:
        result[k].extend(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line solution using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 10, 11), (5, 7, 8)]

result = (pd.DataFrame(lst).groupby(0).agg(set)
            .apply(lambda x: x[1].union(x[2]), axis=1).to_dict())
```

Basically, first you group all your tuples having the same first element. Then you build sets with the remaining elements of the tuples. You use the `union` operation on sets sharing the first element. Finally you build the dictionary from the resulting dataframe.

Here is the result:

```
>>> result
{1: {11, 3, 2, 10}, 5: {8, 7}}
```